# YouTube API 'orderby=duration' not handling the entire playlist, just the newest videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to build a little JavaScript program to query the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol) for a given playlist, ordered by duration. Everything works otherwise perfectly, but the ordering does not account for the whole playlist, just the 25 newest videos on it! Here's a minimum complete working [example as a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKcnb/1/) and here's the JavaScript part of it:

```js
var playlistId = "UUAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug";    
jQuery.getJSON(
    "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/"+playlistId+"?v=2&orderby=duration&alt=json", 
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(key, val) {
            var title = val.title.$t;
            var url = val.content.src;
            var duration = val.media$group.yt$duration.seconds;
            var minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
            var seconds = (duration % 60);

            if( seconds < 10 ) seconds = "0"+seconds;

            var newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
            newRow.append("<td><a href='"+url+"'>"+title+"</a></td>");
            newRow.append("<td class='dur'>"+minutes+":"+seconds+"</td>");
            $("#videos").append(newRow);
        });
    }
);
```

I have tried this in both XML and JSON and I have also tried other kinds of searches besides the playlist search. Having the API sort just the newest videos of the result seems quite pointless. **How exactly do I retrieve the longest or shortest videos of a playlist**, or those uploaded by a given user for that matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

I don't think the functionality you want is available. Ordering by duration is not even available on YouTube itself. I think you will need to use `max-results` and `start-index` to fetch blocks of videos. You can then sort the compiled list by duration.

Here's a working example of one possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/PKcnb/8

---

I found where Google says this explicity not possible.

[YouTube API v2.0 – Video Feed Types: Videos uploaded by a specific user](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos)

> This section explains how to retrieve a feed containing all of the
>   videos uploaded by a specific user. **You should not include [search
>   parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Custom_parameters) in requests to retrieve an uploaded videos feed**. The
>   parameters will generate a feed from YouTube's search index,
>   effectively restricting the result set to indexed, public videos,
>   rather than returning a complete list of the user's uploaded videos.

It goes on to say:

> To request a feed of all videos uploaded by the currently logged-in
>   user, send a GET request to the following URL. This request requires
>   an authentication token, which enables YouTube to identify the user.

So, it may be possible but you will have to test it using an authentication token.

---

**Original Post**

1. The [API docs for `orderby`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#orderbysp) make it sound like only the response is sorted.

   > The orderby parameter, which is supported for video feeds and playlist feeds, specifies the method that will be used to order entries in the API response.
2. Also, [the `max-results` tag](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#max-resultssp) will let you specify how many items to return.
3. [Here's an example of how you could pull more (50 in this example)](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/UUAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug?v=2&orderby=duration&alt=json&max-results=50) results already sorted. Looks like you might have to request as many as you can and then sort. Definitely not ideal.
4. [Retrieving a user's playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_playlists)

Comment: You'd think sorting the results server side would be an overall cheaper operation than replying to a dozen or more individual queries without sorting anything... Definitely not ideal, like you said.

Comment: @ZeroOne, I agree. I really don't understand the logic of why they would have it execute that way.

Comment: This link might shed a little more light on the topic. http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really see how that link is related? The API also mentions that some queries will provide you with cached results while others won't. However, I'd be perfectly happy even with cached results, as long as they were ordered the way I want... :/

Comment: Did my latest edit clarify what's available? I think it answers your question.

Comment: I think it only says that if you include search parameters, the results will be cached and not necessarily entirely up to date. I wouldn't mind that as long as I got any results in the correct order...

Comment: Seems that I need to accept this answer, even though it wasn't what I was hoping for. ;/

Comment: I went ahead and created the code to pull all the videos from a user/playlist. http://jsfiddle.net/PKcnb/4/ There are a few ways to move forward. Sort the table, change the code to consolidate the XML and sort that first, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: [Correctly implemented sorting for both duration and title](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14105087/1085891): http://jsfiddle.net/PKcnb/8/